# How to install mfpdev-cli to offline environment?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, offline, npm-install

I am trying to setup offline (does not have internet access) OS X machine for MobileFirst Platform 8.0 development, and failing to install MobileFirst CLI.
I am referring to [this article](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/03/31/howto-set-up-an-offline-ibm-mobilefirst-8-0-development-environment/).
I have installed `8.0.0.0-MFPF-DevKit-MacOSX-IF2016080923.zip` on the offline machine, then `run.sh` and `console.sh`.
Development server has successfully launched, and now I can access to Operations Console.
I have downloaded `mfpdev-cli.tar` from the Console, and followed the article I cited above.

1. Copy `mfpdev-cli.tar` to online machine.
2. On the online machine, `npm --cache ./.cache install mfpdev-cli.tar`
3. Archive .cache directory, and copy the archive file to the offline machine.
4. On the offline machine, `unarchive .cache directory`.
5. `sudo npm install --cache ./.cache ./mfpdev-cli.tar -g`

Then, I got below:

> npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/http-proxy/-/http-proxy-1.13.2.tgz
>   npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443

Those `ERR!` and `WARN` repeats for many other packages.
And at last:

> npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
>   npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--cache" "./.cache" "./mfpdev-cli.tar" "-g"
>   npm ERR! node v4.5.0
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
>   npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
>   npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
>   npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
>   
>   npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
>   npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>   npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
>   npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
>   npm ERR! network 
>   npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>   npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>   
>   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/babatch/Downloads/mfpdev-cli/npm-debug.log

How do I install `mfpdev-cli` on offline machine?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that npm is attempting to contact its online repository still due to some file dependency on the http-proxy package.

What you can do is to get/add this dependency independently and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried some methods, and finally it got working.
The procedure is below:

1. On the online machine, `npm install ./mfpdev-cli.tar` (without -g)
2. `cd node_modules`
3. `tar -cvzf mfpdev-cli.tgz mfpdev-cli` and copy mfpdev-cli.tgz just created to the offline machine.
4. On the offline machine, `tar -xvzf mfpdev-cli.tgz`
5. `sudo cp -r mfpdev-cli /usr/local/lib/node_modules`
6. `cd /usr/local/bin`
7. `sudo ln -s ../lib/node_modules/mfpdev-cli/bin/cli.js ./mfpdev`

At present, it seems to be working fine.